# What is the "simplest" to install restructured-text to TeX software (for windows)

Tags: tex-core, conversion, windows

I am looking for a simple software (for windows) that can turn the reStructured-text format into TeX.

"Simple" to install means that you can basically unzip a file with the software, and you could then run in CMD something like:

```
reST2TeX.exe input.reST output.tex
```

And it would work.

I know of [docutil](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/), but I want something that doesn't first require me to download python just to compile it.  Something more like [tth](http://hutchinson.belmont.ma.us/tth/) for TeX -> HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/index.html)

Comment: Thanks.  How is it in creating html from tex vs tth?

Comment: @tal: I've no idea; never tried tth